# Align 3 columns, middle column HR adjustable

Tags: html, css

i have this section:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve, is to have the left span, with a padding on the right, then on the middle the HR, and on the right the span with the price, but I want to have the price align to the right, and make the HR adjustable, so it always ends on the price and starts after the first span. I'm not being able to achieve this, no matter what I try.

Here is the code:

```
    <div class="ementaspan"><span class="span1"><h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-600 text-color-118181-color" style="
    display:  inline-block;
"><span>Creme de Baunilha</span></h5></span> <span><hr class="dotted border-accent-color separator-no-padding" style="width: 90%;border-top-width: 4px;"></span><span class="span3"><h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-300"><span>1,60€</span></h5></span></div>
```

Creme de Nata 1,60€

And the CSS:

```
.ementaspan span h5, .ementaspan hr {
    display: inline-block !important;
}


.ementaspan {
    text-align: left !important;
}

.ementaspan .span1 {
    width: 25% !important;
}

.ementaspan .span1 h5 {
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.ementaspan hr {
    width: 50% !important;
}
.ementaspan .span3 {
    width: 25% !important;
}

.ementaspan .span3 h5 {
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to do it with flex

```css
.maindiv {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.maindiv .div1 {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.maindiv .div2 {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.maindiv .div2 hr {
  height: 0;
  background: none;
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #f00;
  border-top: none !important;
  margin: 0 0 4px !important;
}
.maindiv .div3 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="div1">Creme de Baunilha</div>
  <div class="div2"><hr></div>
  <div class="div3">1,60€</div>
</div>
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="div1">Creme de Nata</div>
  <div class="div2"><hr></div>
  <div class="div3">11,60€</div>
</div>
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="div1">Baunilha e Noz</div>
  <div class="div2"><hr></div>
  <div class="div3">1,60€</div>
</div>
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="div1">Baunilha e Cookies</div>
  <div class="div2"><hr></div>
  <div class="div3">121,60€</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe add some other lines/products. It's hard to tell it works with only one! And why didn't you use any of the classes of the OP?

Comment: If price is >= 10,00€, the border right end isn't aligned. Don't know if you can do something about it!

Comment: it's possible to set a minimum width to div3 and align the text left. but I think the current options where the prices are aligned right looks better.

Comment: Thanks! This works here! But im using uncode theme, on wordpress. When i past your code as raw html, and the css, the right div with the price doesn't align... https://confeitariaframboesa.pt/novo/produtos/gelados/

Comment: just add "align-items: center;" to the "maindiv", it'll center the elements vertically. =I'll add it to my answer

Comment: and at the site you linked to  the hr has top and bottom margin. if you'll remove them or change to smaller top and bottom margins it'll look better.

Comment: THanks! Its all good now! To make the items align vertically to the center, and make the border align on the bottom, is it easy? Also i noticed there is a grey line on the top of the dotted border?

Comment: the gray line is border-top from somewhere else in your code. i added a few modifications to my code to remove your gray line and to align it to the bottom (align-items: flex-end) and not the middle

Answer (score 0):

Playing a little with your code,

I ended up with this:

```css
.ementaspan {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.ementaspan span h5 {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.ementaspan .span2 {
  flex: auto;
  padding: 20px; /* Instead of padding on span1 and span3 */
}

.ementaspan hr {
  background: none;
  color: transparent;
  border: 0; /* Resets hr style */
  border-bottom: 4px dotted #f00;
}

.ementaspan .span3 {
  width: 25% !important;
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="ementaspan">
  <span class="span1">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-600 text-color-118181-color" style="
    display:  inline-block;
"><span>Creme de Baunilha</span></h5>
  </span>

  <span class="span2">
    <hr class="dotted border-accent-color separator-no-padding">
  </span>

  <span class="span3">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-300"><span>1,60€</span></h5>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="ementaspan">
  <span class="span1">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-600 text-color-118181-color" style="
    display:  inline-block;
"><span>Creme de Nata</span></h5>
  </span>

  <span class="span2">
    <hr class="dotted border-accent-color separator-no-padding">
  </span>

  <span class="span3">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-300"><span>2,60€</span></h5>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="ementaspan">
  <span class="span1">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-600 text-color-118181-color" style="
    display:  inline-block;
"><span>Baunilha e Noz</span></h5>
  </span>

  <span class="span2">
    <hr class="dotted border-accent-color separator-no-padding">
  </span>

  <span class="span3">
    <h5 class="font-150690 h5 font-weight-300"><span>10,60€</span></h5>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note that I kept all your classes and your html structure.
The only HTML modification is the `span2` class,
then you'll only need to copy/paste the CSS to try it!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this, is that the line will always start at the same point, and i want it to start right after the text, no matter how many caracthers the text have...

Comment: Thanks for the help men! Check it https://confeitariaframboesa.pt/novo/produtos/gelados/  The only problem is that the div is not as wide as the top answer... And the border is on the top, i wanted the name and price to align center, and the border to align to the bottom of that.